# Query a firestore document with a timestamp field inside a nested map

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

My Documents are structured something like this -

```
fieldOne = "value1"
fieldTwo = "value2"
fieldThree = "value3<Map1 = flights <Map2 = [flight_number] = <travel_date = TimeStamp>>>"
```

Here the `flight_number` (LH760 in image below) key is dynamic and I don't know its value beforehand. Additionally, there could be multiple flight_number's

[image: Screenshot of actual data]

I want to find all documents where the travel_date is equal to today's date. How can I most efficiently write a query (in Kotlin)?

I tried to filter by `created` (as a tutorial for myself - not as a solution for my requirement) but zero docs were returned. so I cant wrap my head around how to query within such a complex nested structure -

```
.whereEqualTo("created", LocalDateTime.now())
```

Please note: `created` timestamp can be different from `travel_date` timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the Firestore API to query in a specific field in an array or on the dynamic keys of a map.

What you *can* do is modify/augment the data model to allow your use-case. Since you want to query on travel date, add a top-level array field `travel_dates` where you store all the `travel_date` values that you also store in the `flights` field already in a format like `"2023-01-17"` (for January 17, 2023).

With that field in place, you can query on the new `travel_dates` field to get all documents for today with something like:

```
.whereArrayContains("travel_dates", "2023-01-17")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the mapdescriptor package.
This package allows users to convert DateTime values to strings and vice versa in a given Map of key-value pairs. This package is especially useful for users who receive data in Map form from Firestore and need to convert the ISO 8601 string values for their application needs. The package provides four methods - convertTimeStampToStr and convertStrToTimeStamp - that handle the conversion of TimeStamp values to strings and vice versa respectively. -containsTimeStamp and containsISO8601String - that check if a map contains timestamp or string format of timestamp respectively.

Example :
**1-Convert all timestamps in a nested JSON object to ISO 8601 strings:**

```
    import 'package:mapdescriptor/mapdescriptor.dart';

void main() {
  final myMap = {
    'name': 'Sami Youssuf',
    'age': 45,
    'timestamp': Timestamp(1560523991, 286000000),
    'activities': {
      'activity1': {
        'type': 'sport',
        'start': Timestamp(1560523991, 286000000),
      },
      'activity2': {
        'type': 'Sing',
        'start': Timestamp(1560523991, 286000000),
      }
    }
  };

  final convertedMap = MapDescriptor().convertTimeStampToStr(myMap);
  print(convertedMap['timestamp']); // should print an ISO 8601 string of this date ex :1990-12-12T05:14:15.541Z
  print(convertedMap['activities']['activity1']['start']); // should print an ISO 8601 string of this date ex :1990-12-12T05:14:15.541Z
  print(convertedMap['activities']['activity2']['start']); // should print an ISO 8601 string of this date ex :1990-12-12T05:14:15.541Z
```

2- Convert all ISO 8601 strings in a nested JSON object to TimeStamp :

```
import 'package:mapdescriptor/mapdescriptor.dart';

void main() {
  final myMap = {
    'name': 'Andrew Tate',
    'age': 30,
    'birthday': "1990-12-12T05:14:15.541Z",
    'activities': {
      'activity1': {
        'type': 'Boxing',
        'start': "1999-07-04T05:14:15.541Z"),
      },
      'activity2': {
        'type': 'Netflix',
        'start': "2019-01-06T04:15:15.746Z",
      }
    }
  };

  final convertedMap = MapDescriptor().convertStrToTimeStamp(myMap);
  print(convertedMap['birthday']); // should print Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)
  print(convertedMap['activities']['activity1']['start']); // should print Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)
  print(convertedMap['activities']['activity2']['start']); // should print Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)
}
```

**Note** : You can also check if the map contains any TimeStamp or ISO 8601 String value by using containsTime(yourMap) & containsISO8601String(yourMap) respectively .
[Package link on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/mapdescriptor)